# What would be the elegant ways to wrap string with quotes in python?

Tags: python, string

I can only think of 2 ways but they are not no where near elegant in my opinion

```
"'" + 'hello' + "'"
```

and

```
"'%s'" % 'hello'
```

Can anyone share the better ways ?

Comment: Do you just want to append the string you have with quotes?

Answer (score 4):

You can use its `repr` representation.

```
>>> s = 'hello'
```

Using old-style formatting

```
>>> print '%r' % s
'hello'
```

Using new-style formatting

```
>>> print '{!r}'.format(s)
'hello'
```

Comment: He wants the string to contain quotes, yours does not.

Comment: @diewland if you find answer correct and helping please mark it correct, :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use triple quotes.

```
>>> s='''This is a string containing "quoted words. Nice, isn't it?"'''
>>> print s
This is a string containing "quoted words. Nice, isn't it?"
```